# Infinite subset of a compact topological space

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I just can't quite get this question:

Let $X$ be a compact space, $B_{n}$, n $\in \mathbb{N}$ a closed non-empty subset such that $B_{n+1} \subseteq B_{n}$. Show that $$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} B_{n} \neq 0$$ Deduce that an infinite subset of a compact topological space has limit points.

I was thinking of using an inductive argument, but I'm not sure if this would work for an infinite intersection? Also I have no idea how this implies that an infinite subset of a compact topological space has limit points?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Suppose $\bigcap_n B_n=\varnothing$, take  complements of $B_n$ and try to use compactness.